# Three column header using floating elements

Tags: html, css

#### What the Header Should Look Like

This is how the header should look like.

[image: Header2]

#### What it currently looks like

[image: Header]

As you can see, my header isn't looking too good... I seem to be having some floating issues.

#### Current Header Code

Here is the HMTL I used to generate my header.

I'm trying to center the `h1`, float the logo to the left completely and have the `h2` display beside the logo. The publish date and publisher are fine.

```
<header>
    <ul style="list-style-type:none;float:right;">
      <li style="float:left;">
        <img src="C:\Logo.jpg" alt="Logo"/>
      </li>
      <li style="float:left;">
        <h2>Statuts de Production</h2>
      </li>
      <li style="float:right;">
        <h1 style="margin-bottom:0px">Machines en cours d'assemblage</h1>
      </li>
      <ul style="list-style-type:none;float:right;">
        <li>
          Dernière mise à jour: <xsl:value-of select="Table/Publish/DateEntry"/>
        </li>
        <li>
          Par: <xsl:value-of select="Table/Publish/Username"/>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </ul>
  </header>
```

Am I not using the right approach? Should I use a table instead of an unordered list?

Comment: What is the reason for `<ul>` and `<li>` in header?

Comment: @hr_117 There is none really ... I'm just pretty noob when it comes to web programming.

Comment: Change your **tags** to html and css (only).

Comment: As a general rule, use a CSS file instead of inline styles. Also, this is not at all an XSLT question.

Comment: @Tomalak I usually do use a CSS file, much easier ... I just haven't understood how to attach a CSS file to my XSLT document.

Comment: You don't attach it at all. You create a `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="your.css" />` element in the header.

Comment: @Tomalak, thanks I'll go ahead and apply that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to vertical align the list items and indent the middle one, just remove the styles from the HTML and use this external CSS (using external CSS is the **first** thing to improve your approach):

```
ul { display: block; list-style-type:none; height: 50px;  }
li { display: inline-block; vertical-align: middle; }
ul ul { display: inline-block; }
ul ul li { display: block; }
```

and set the padding to each list item as you want, the third item might be floated right.

**Second:** you can not use image path on your HDD `C:\Logo.jpg` to enable the access from clients, use the `http://...` protocol.

**Third:** you can not use `ul` as direct child of `ul`. Only `li`s are allowed inside `ul`

```
<ul>
  <li>item 1</li>
  <li>item 2</li>
  <li>
    <ul>
      <li>subitem 1</li>
      <li>subitem 2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

Dose the following help you? it is designed such that the hight is constant.

```
<div style='position:relative; padding:0px 200px 0px 200px; background-color:gray;height:20px;box-sizing:border-box;'>
    <div style='position:absolute;background-color:yellow; left:0px; top:0px; height:100%;width:200px;'>
        left pannel
    </div>
    <div style='position:absolute;background-color:yellow; right:0px; top:0px; height:100%; width:200px;'>
        right pannel.
    </div>
    <div style='box-sizing:border-box;width:100%;text-align:center;'>
        Center
    </div>
</div>
```

You can see it also [here](http://jsfiddle.net/D84B9/).